Getting Save Count for a particular post
Is there any way to see how many users have saved a particular post in Stack Overflow? For example, I have saved the following post in Stack Overflow.
Ansible-galaxy throws ImportError: No module named yaml
I wanted the count one if I am the only user who saved this post. If it's saved by another user, I want 2.

Everything about saves is private. All you can see is your own data.

Saves are private to a user, by design.
Therefor there is no public info if a post is saved by anyone, let alone by how many.
This change to make Saves private was a deliberate choice and the opposite of what we were used to with the feature called "Favorite". Favorites of users were public and available in the Votes table of the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, for example. That data is gone (technically you could find them in older data dumps from before 2023 but that is of no use for todays use cases).

But my Favourite marking has stopped, I think.

Yes, all favorites, even historic ones have been erased from the db.
